# When adding events to FullCalendar they are duplicated - multiple calls made to add event without cause

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar, addition

I am using FullCallendar and Jquery. I made a google calendar like interface and pull events from a json file. When a user clicks on a day a div opens for them to enter info click add event and the event is added. On the second click when the user clicks add event two events are added, one on the first clicked day and the second on the selected day. On the third click 3 events are added and so on. Here is the code:

var c = 0;

```
function cleanEventBubble(){
    $('#event').hide();
    $('td').removeClass('selDay');
    $('#eventDate').text('');
    $('#calEvent,input:text').val('');
}

function createEvent(date, allDay, jsEvent, View, selCell){
    //Clean the event bubble and calendar
    cleanEventBubble();
    $(selCell).addClass('selDay');
    $('#eventDate').append(date.toDateString());
    $('#event').css('left', jsEvent.pageX);
    $('#event').css('top', jsEvent.pageY);
    $('#event').show();

    $('#btnAddEvent').click(function(){addEvent(date, $('#title').val(), c)});
}

function addEvent(date, title, id){
    $.ajax({
            type:'get',
    <cfoutput>url:  '#strURL#'</cfoutput>,
            data:{
                method:'addEvent',
                user:1,
                title:title,
                allDay:'true',
                start:$.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
                },
            dataType:   'json',
            success: function(data, status){alert('response: ' + data);},
            error: function(data){$('#returnMess').html(data);}

    });
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' )
    cleanEventBubble();
}

/**/
function removeEvent(id){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
}

function updateEvent(id, title){
    var event = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', id);
    event.title = title;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    //Create JQuery connection to obj
    $('#event').hide();
    //Make event bubble draggable
    $('#event').draggable();

    $('#evBubbleClose').click(cleanEventBubble);
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here date, allDay, jsEvent, view
        dayClick:function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
           createEvent(date, allDay, jsEvent, view, this);
        },
        <cfoutput>events: '#strURL#'+'?wsdl&method=getEvents'</cfoutput> ,
        theme: true,
        header: {left: 'prev,next today', center: 'title', right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' }, 
        editable:true
    });

    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvents');

});
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's the solution without boolean flags :)

Instead of `$(this).remove();`

use

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEvents', event.id );
```

[See documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEvents/)

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you have two click events that create events? (I'm not sure where you 'button' is)

The first 'add event' is called on the dayClick:

```
  dayClick:function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view){
           createEvent(date, allDay, jsEvent, view, this);
        },
```

So is the second event created when the addEvent button is clicked?

```
$('#btnAddEvent').click(function(){addEvent(date, $('#title').val(), c)});
```

Try only using the dayClick to add events and see if that works as expected and then go from there.

Comment: actually the createEvent method only shows a div that has a form to set the event properties. There is a button on the div that when clicked adds the event to the db and calls the refetchEvents method. What I think is happening is that the memory is not cleared so on the second click on the calendar jsevent happens twice. On the third click it happens 3 times, etc. I viewed the output and it shows that the memory is not cleared of the previous event and so occurs again. Something like that anyway. I set up a flag that does not allow the event to fire more than once.